# How to place a line break between every character in ConTeXt?

Tags: line-breaking, context, context-mkiv

I have some text appearing in a macro, like this:

```
\printascolumn{This is some text.}
```

How can I place a line break between each letter or printed symbol, such that it appears like this?

```
T
h
i
s

i
s

s
o
m
e

t
e
x
t
.
```

Comment: Search for `\handletokens`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ConTeXt provides a macro `\handletokens` which passes each token to a command. You can use `\handletokens` to print text vertically (or along a path, as shown in the MetaFun manual). In the example below, I also horizontally align the letters, which gives a nicer output than the default left aligned letters.

```
\define[1]\AddLine{#1\crlf}

\define[1]\printascolumn
    {\framed[align=middle, frame=off]{\handletokens #1 \with\AddLine}}

\starttext
\printascolumn{This is some text}
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: +1 for using the right interface and aligning the letters:-)

Answer (score 8):

Context may have something packaged, this just uses TeX primitives.

[image]

```
\def\printascolumn#1{%
  \printa#1\relax}

\def\printa{\futurelet\tmp\printb}

\def\printb{%
\ifx\tmp\relax\printe\fi
\hbox{\tmp}%
\ifx\tmp\spchar
   \expandafter\printc
\else
   \expandafter\printd
\fi
  }

\def\printe#1\fi#2\fi{\fi}

\def\tmp#1{%
\let\spchar= #1%
\def\printc#1{\printa}}
\tmp{ }

\def\printd#1{\printa}

\printascolumn{This is some text.}

\bye
```

Comment: Interestingly, this is the [exact implementation](http://gitorious.org/context/context/blobs/origin/tex/context/base/syst-aux.mkiv#line5893) of `\handletokens` in ConTeXt (except for different variable names, and a slightly different interface).

Answer (score 4):

While the approach with `\handletokens` has its merits, it
operates on token level and will fail if you have, say, an
hbox in the argument.
(Try `\printascolumn{foo \hbox{bar} baz}` ...)
This is true for math mode as well.

Luckily we can do the same on node level, avoiding all
the expansion issues and whatnot.
The only prerequisite is that we must know which nodes to
insert a break after.
For our purpose it will suffice if we handle nodes of type
*glyph* (“characters”), *hlist* and *vlist* (boxes).
We specify their corresponding ids (type int) in the table
`breakafter` using the convenient table `nodes.nodecodes`
that is created with every Context run.

Then we create an *action*, which is just the Context jargon
for LuaTeX callbacks (more or less, anyways ...).
This action is required to be accessible from `_G` ([locals
won’t work because of the implementation](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20121002.123744.eb2d1134.en.html)), so we assign them
the namespace `document`.
We add it to the list `processors` which in many respects works
like the `pre_linebreak_filter`: receive the head of a node list,
manipulate the list, return a list.
Once registered this action can be toggled on and off through
the functions `nodes.enableaction()` and `nodes.disableaction()`.

Inside the action we walk the paragraph node list.
Once we encounter a node whose type is set in the `breakafter`
table, we append a -10k penalty and a glue.
This triggers a carriage return.
Also, we must handle non-empty hboxes separately.[*]
It is necessary to omit anything until the first glyph node.
(For some obscure reason we can’t rely on the function
`node.first_glyph` here, because it will return `nil`
even though there are character nodes inside the box.)

One caveat: this solution as it is works on entire paragraphs
only.
To restrict it to some part of the paragraph list should be
possible but would complicate things quite a bit.

[*] Hint: in Context the “processors” action is
[not totally equivalent](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20120626.125050.6646c2bc.en.html)
to the `pre_linebreak_filter`: namely because it is
*applied to the `hpack_filter` callback as well*.
Under other circumstances this does mess up the iteration
order quite thoroughly but here it can be considered a
benefit for we don’t need to handle node lists recursively.

[image: demo]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                          implementation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\startluacode
  --- 1. namespace, required for callback insertion
  document = document or { }

  --- 2. reserve some locals for convenience and a marginal performance
  ---    gain
  local copy_node       = node.copy
  local count_nodes     = node.count
  local traverse_nodes  = node.traverse
  local new_node        = node.new
  local find_tail       = node.tail

  local tasks     = nodes.tasks
  local nodecodes = nodes.nodecodes

  --- 3. prepare our breaks. a break consists of (1) a penalty
  ---    and (2) an infinite horizontal glue.
  local generic_fill                = new_node(nodecodes.glue)
  generic_fill.spec                 = new_node(nodecodes.gluespec)
  generic_fill.spec.width           = 0
  generic_fill.spec.stretch         = 2^16 --> 1pt
  generic_fill.spec.shrink          = 0
  generic_fill.spec.stretch_order   = 2
  local generic_break               = new_node(nodecodes.penalty)
  generic_break.penalty             = -10^4

  --- 4. which nodes do we intend to inserts breaks after?
  local breakafter = {
    [nodecodes.glyph] = true,
    [nodecodes.hlist] = true,
    [nodecodes.vlist] = true,
  }

  --- 5. the main “action” (Contextese for callback). nothing special:
  ---    we hop over the node list prior to linebreaking and ensure that
  ---    every node of type “glyph”, as long as it is not the last node
  ---    in the list, is followed by a break.
  local glyph_breaking glyph_breaking = function (head)
    for n in traverse_nodes(head) do
      local id, len = n.id, count_nodes(nodecodes.glyph, n)
      if id == nodecodes.hlist and n.list then -- unbox
        local hd = n.list
        while hd and hd.id ~= nodecodes.glyph do
          hd = hd.next
        end
        if hd then
          local tl = find_tail(hd)
          tl.next, hd.prev         = n.next, n.prev
          n.prev.next, n.next.prev = hd, tl
          n = tl
        end
      end
      if breakafter[id] then
        local nxt = n.next
        if nxt then
          local brk  = copy_node(generic_break)
          local fill = copy_node(generic_fill)
          n.next, brk.prev    = brk, n
          brk.next, fill.prev = fill, brk
          fill.next, nxt.prev = nxt, fill
        end
      end
    end
    return head
  end

  document.glyph_breaking = glyph_breaking

  --- 6. register the glyph breaking as an action and activate it.
  tasks.appendaction ("processors", "before", "document.glyph_breaking")
  tasks.disableaction("processors",           "document.glyph_breaking")

  commands.start_as_column = function ( )
    tasks.enableaction("processors", "document.glyph_breaking")
  end
  commands.stop_as_column = function ( )
    tasks.disableaction("processors", "document.glyph_breaking")
  end
\stopluacode

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                              macros
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% 7. user interface commands. these work on per-paragraph base only as
%%    the callback is only triggered before hyphenation.
\def\startascolumn{\par\bgroup\dontcomplain\ctxcommand{start_as_column()}}
\def\stopascolumn{\par\ctxcommand{stop_as_column()}\egroup}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                              testing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\starttext
  Normal text.
  \startascolumn
    foo \hbox{bar \framed[corner=00,align=right]{baz}} xyzzy
    \m{\pi(x)\sim\frac{x}{\ln x}.} %% <== looks funny ...
  \stopascolumn
  Normal text.

  % \startascolumn
  %   \input knuth
  % \stopascolumn
\stoptext
```